# I wanna know how to use lots of OR CLAUSE. Thanks

Tags: sql, oracle

error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT B.MILESTONE_NAME, D.TASK_NAME, F.FIELD_NAME, F.FIELD_ALIAS, G.VALUE 
FROM TBL_APPLICATIONS tblapp
  INNER JOIN TBL_WORKFLOWS tblwflow ON tblwflow.APPLICATION_FK = tblapp.APPLICATION_PK
  INNER JOIN TBL_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION A ON A.WORKFLOW_FK = tblwflow.WORKFLOW_PK
  INNER JOIN TBL_MILESTONE B ON B.MILESTONE_PK = A.START_MILESTONE_FK  OR B.MILESTONE_PK = A.END_MILESTONE_FK
  INNER JOIN TBL_TASK_FOR_MILESTONE C ON  C.MILESTONE_FK = B.MILESTONE_PK 
  INNER JOIN TBL_TASK D ON  D.TASK_PK = C.TASK_FK 
  INNER JOIN TBL_REQ_FOR_TASK E ON  E.TASK_FK = D.TASK_PK 
  INNER JOIN TBL_TASK_REQUIREMENTS F ON F.TASK_REQUIREMENT_PK = E.TASK_REQUIREMENT_FK 
  INNER JOIN TBL_PROJECT_REQ_VALUES G ON G.TASK_REQUIREMENT_FK = F.TASK_REQUIREMENT_PK 
  INNER JOIN TBL_PROJECTS H ON H.PROJECT_PK = G.PROJECTS_FK
WHERE PROJECT_PK = :PROJECT_ID 
  OR B.MILESTONE_NAME 
  OR D.TASK_NAME 
  OR F.FIELD_NAME 
  OR F.FIELD_ALIAS 
  OR G.VALUE IS NULL
GROUP BY B.MILESTONE_NAME, D.TASK_NAME, F.FIELD_NAME, F.FIELD_ALIAS, G.VALUE
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  It is not clear from the non-working code.

Comment: i want a result that in 4 column, i will get a result in just 1 column then the rest is null. 2nd: i want a result that in 4 column, i will get a result in just 2 column then the rest is null. 3rd i want a result that in 4 column, i will get a result in just 3 column then the rest is null. that's why i have a condition of or clause and is null

Comment: result: 
1st:
B.MILESTONE_NAME = data
D.TASK_NAME = null
 F.FIELD_NAME = null
 F.FIELD_ALIAS, G.VALUE = null
second:
result: 

B.MILESTONE_NAME = data
D.TASK_NAME = data
 F.FIELD_NAME = null
 F.FIELD_ALIAS, G.VALUE = null
3rd:
result: 

B.MILESTONE_NAME = data
D.TASK_NAME = data
 F.FIELD_NAME = data
 F.FIELD_ALIAS, G.VALUE = null
either of them

Comment: it doesnt matter if one column has just a data. but i want a result include null from other column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid Oracle SQL:

```
WHERE 
    PROJECT_PK = :PROJECT_ID 
    OR B.MILESTONE_NAME 
    OR D.TASK_NAME 
    OR F.FIELD_NAME 
    OR F.FIELD_ALIAS 
    OR G.VALUE IS NULL
```

You would need to repeat the `IS NULL` condition:

```
WHERE 
    PROJECT_PK = :PROJECT_ID 
    OR B.MILESTONE_NAME IS NULL
    OR D.TASK_NAME IS NULL
    OR F.FIELD_NAME IS NULL
    OR F.FIELD_ALIAS IS NULL
    OR G.VALUE IS NULL
```

Side note: the following part of your query:

```
INNER JOIN TBL_MILESTONE B 
    ON B.MILESTONE_PK = A.START_MILESTONE_FK  OR B.MILESTONE_PK = A.END_MILESTONE_FK
```

Can be shorten with the `IN` operator:

```
INNER JOIN TBL_MILESTONE B 
    ON B.MILESTONE_PK IN (A.START_MILESTONE_FK, A.END_MILESTONE_FK)
```